# Имея CLLocationCoordinate2D узнать город и улицу

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios, iphone

День добрый. Не могу отыскать в нете ответ на свой квет. Сервер мне отдает  CLLocationCoordinate2D 2 координаты. Как с их помощью мне узнать город и улицу ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например Питер:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = 59.939095;
zoomLocation.longitude = 30.315868;
```

Тогда:

```
CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
CLLocation *local = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:zoomLocation.latitude longitude:zoomLocation.longitude];

[ceo reverseGeocodeLocation: local
          completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     1)
     NSLog(@"addressFull %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

     2)

     NSLog(@"country %@",placemark.country);
     NSLog(@"locality %@",placemark.locality);
     NSLog(@"name %@",placemark.name);
     NSLog(@"postalCode %@",placemark.postalCode);
     NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);

     3)
     NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
     NSLog(@" %@",locatedAt);         
 }];
```

Результаты:

1)

```
Name = Schlossplatz;
State = "Sankt Petersburg";
Street = "Dvortsovaya ploshchad' 2";
SubAdministrativeArea = "Sankt Petersburg";
SubThoroughfare = 2;
Thoroughfare = "Dvortsovaya ploshchad'";
ZIP = 191186;
```

2)

```
country Russland
locality Sankt Petersburg
name Schlossplatz
postalCode 191186
location <+59.93983200,+30.31559240> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 22/05/14 15 h 38 min 53 s GMT+03:00
```

3)

```
Schlossplatz, Dvortsovaya ploshchad' 2, Sankt Petersburg, Russland, 191186
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError     *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
}];
```

[CLPlacemark Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

Можно юзать открытую апи гугламапс:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452
```

Comment: То что надо, спасибо!